# The relationship between state url of UI-Router and REST API url

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-ui-router

Is there any relationship between the state url of UI-Router and REST API url in angularjs?

Comment: Router represents your views, i.e. *states of your frontend*. REST API is about accessing the data from backend. There may be similar endpoints in REST API corresponding to your view but this is not necessary. I think you have to narrow your question.

Answer (score 1):

NO.

The UI-Router `state`'s ***url*** represents current *state*, optionally with some settings *(called `params`)*. That even could be working without any API in place. It is just a **client** (browser) side handling.

REST API ***url***, is a way how to get or set data - via **server-client** communication